# When I open CMD no window pops up

Tags: windows, display, cmd.exe, window, buffer

When I launch `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` no window pops up.

I see it in my task bar, but I have to right-click the task bar, then hit "New Window".

When I go to PowerShell and type `Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` same thing.

What did I do?

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer ?

Comment: @Elie I didn't. I got down voted too :(

Comment: At least does the solution work ,

Comment: @Elie I'll have to try on Monday, but I'm wondering if I modified the properties of the window. Like when you right click the bar and go to properties? I'll have to check

Comment: I think once you move it you don't need to modify anything but worth the shot

Answer (score 0):

I think it's opening somewhere you can't see it in further corner next time you open command prompt just hit " alt + space + m " and move with your keyboard arrows till you see the window

Comment: I'll try this on Monday :)